# 365 Powershell, how to filter out .onmicrosoft.com results from proxyaddresses

Tags: powershell, filter, dns

I am attempting to export all users from 365 with a specific email domain to csv
so i can then remove the domain from one tenancy and move it to another.

the command I'm using is

```
Get-MsolUser -All -DomainName mydomain.co.nz | Select-Object DisplayName, FirstName, LastName, UserPrincipalName, @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { $_.ProxyAddresses -join ","}}
```

which gets me

> FirstName LastName    UserPrincipalName   ProxyAddresses

the proxy addresses comes out comma-separated, i.e.:

> user.name@domain.co.nz,user.name@onmicrosoft.com

what I want to do is filter out addresses like `user.name@onmicrosoft.com` from the proxyaddress results, as i do not want to import these at the other end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try :

```
Get-MsolUser -All -DomainName mydomain.co.nz | Select-Object DisplayName, FirstName, LastName, UserPrincipalName, @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { $_.ProxyAddresses -notmatch "@onmicrosoft.com" -join ","}}
```

If it doesn't work , I will edit it again .

**Edited**: (I have changed the operator to "-notmatch" to filter specific items out)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

```
(Get-MsolUser -All -DomainName mydomain.co.nz |?{$_.proxyaddress -notmatch 'onmicrosoft.com'})
```